# Nesting standard type traits with SFINAE fails to compile with g++ 4.8

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

What is the correct process to pass a standard type traits qualified type as an argument to a template class?

I have the following (rather useless but useful to depict my problem) program that qualifies a type via standard type traits before passing to a template class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
struct is_foo
{
    static bool const value = true;
};
template<
    typename Ty,
    bool foo = is_foo<std::remove_reference<Ty>::type>::value
>
struct bar {
    static bool const value = true;
};
int main() {
    int elem;
    std::cout << bar<decltype(elem)>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles fine with VC12 but fails to compile with g++ 4.8 with the following error

```
prog.cpp:11:51: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct is_foo’
  bool foo = is_foo<std::remove_reference<Ty>::type>::value
                                                   ^
prog.cpp:11:51: error:   expected a type, got ‘std::remove_reference< <template-parameter-1-1> >::type’
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:18:33: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  std::cout << bar<decltype(elem)>::value << std::endl;
                                 ^
```

Any idea what might be wrong with my code?

- **Note** If you need to play with the code, here is a version in [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/XYJhB5)
- **Note** Also, it would be quite beneficial if you can refer me back to the standard.
- **Note** If I remove the std::remove_reference call, `bool foo = is_foo<Ty>::value` my code compiles fine. Refer [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/b99224)

Comment: should be `typename std::remove_reference<Ty>::type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `typename` (because `std::remove_reference<Ty>::type` is dependant on a template parameter):

```
template<
typename Ty,
bool foo = is_foo<typename std::remove_reference<Ty>::type>::value>

                  ^^^^^^^
                    Here
```

Also see [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)